# How do I simplify debugging nodejs in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, node.js, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, v8

So for your first `NodeJS` project, you install the [V8 debugger for Eclipse](https://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/wiki/DebuggerTutorial) from [ChromeDevTools](https://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/wiki/EclipseDebugger).

And whenever you have a new `NodeJS` project in Eclipse, what you basically do is duplicate your `Debug Configuration` and make two changes:

- Change the `Source Mapper` that connects the project to the local directory
- Change the `Source Mapper` that connects the project to the local/remote host

This works, no problem.

---

But the list of `Debug Configurations` builds and builds. You'll have to click the debug-dropdown and choose from the list of many debug configurations the one that was meant for your current project.

- Isn't there an easier way to do this?

  1. Have one NodeJS `Debug Configuration` that automatically changes the `Source Mappers` based on the current project? Or;
  2. Save the project's required debug configuration and tie this specific configuration to a shortcutkey or the debug button for the current project, so you don't have to pick it from a list every single time?

Because I always have to click the `Debug As...` drop-down and choose the proper configuration.
[image]

If I just click the `Debug As...` button (the little green bug), I always get this: [image]
Even if I've just debugged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try nodeclipse http://www.nodeclipse.org/ that goes with many ChromeDevTools bugs fixed.

Remote debugging is not possible with Nodeclispe, so install it in other Eclispe instance or get Enide Studio http://sf.net/p/nodeclipse

And if it stil won't be enough, I am glad to share what I know to help you with changing ChromeDevTools in the way you want https://github.com/nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/.

Comment: Although this didn't answer my question, this information might be valuable. But can you elaborate your answer a bit? What is the difference between `NodeEclipse` and CDT/V8-Debugger for Eclipse? What is the benefit of `Enide Studio`? It seems to do a subset of Eclipse features.

Comment: NodeEclipse integrates CDT/V8-Debugger. No configuration is needed, just Run as -> Node Application. Internally RunConfiguration is created automatically and breakpoints in CDT/V8-Debugger and JS Editor are synchronized.

Warning: it is impossible to have unmodified CDT/V8-Debugger and Nodeclipse at the same time.

Enide Studio is Eclipse distribution with some plugins preinstalled.
You can start from vanilla Eclipse as well.

Answer (score 0):

For the second question about key shortcut, check linked Q to [Eclipse - How to assign key shourtcut command to Launch type (Run As type)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855846/eclipse-how-to-assign-key-shourtcut-command-to-launch-type-run-as-type)

Or maybe you want to use Eclipse Runner http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-runner