# Eclipse - How to assign key shourtcut command to Launch type (Run As type)

Tags: java, eclipse, node.js, eclipse-plugin, nodeclipse

In Eclipse IDE in Properties -> General -> Keys
user can assign key binding for most command.

I want to bind <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd> to (for example) Run As -> Node application 
but I cannot find it in the list (there are Run Java Application, Run Maven Build both with <kbd>Alt+Shift+X, some key</kbd> binding)

If desired Launch Type is not in list, how to configure it in plugin project sources?

(Yes, I can relaunch with <kbd>Ctrl+F11</kbd>, but it is not convenient for left hand
and is NOT launching current Editor)

UPDATE: [how do I map a key in eclipse to run the project run configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13493308/how-do-i-map-a-key-in-eclipse-to-run-the-project-run-configuration) suggested <kbd>Alt+R, S, 1</kbd> that is too long.

UPDATE 2:

All related that suggest a bit different solutions:

- [Eclipse Maven Build and Test with One Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273026/one-button-maven-build-and-test-in-eclipse)
- [eclipse: put keyboard shortcuts on specific launch configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015510/eclipse-put-keyboard-shortcuts-on-specific-launch-configurations)
- [How can I bind a specific key to different launch configurations in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125257/how-can-i-bind-a-specific-key-to-different-launch-configurations-in-eclipse)

What exactly `plugin.xml` should have that user could assign Key binding?

Answer (score 3):

Try using Practically Macro Options

Just install it from the eclipse update site

http://puremvcnotificationviewer.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/PracticallyMacroGoogleUpdateSite

After installing and restarting eclipse. Go to
Windows-->Preferences-->Practically Macro options-->Editor Macro Defenitions

Click "New" and select "Editor Macro script (Beanshell)" in Available Commands and click "Add"

Use the following script

```
import org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugPlugin;
import org.eclipse.debug.core.ILaunchConfiguration;
import org.eclipse.debug.core.ILaunch;
import org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugUITools;
    try
    {
      // Terminate process if it already exists from a previous launch 
      org.eclipse.debug.core.ILaunch[] allLaunches=DebugPlugin.getDefault().getLaunchManager().getLaunches();
      for (ILaunch l : allLaunches)
      {              
        if (l.getLaunchConfiguration().getName().equals("YOUR CONFIG NAME"))
        {
          console.write("terminating launch: " );
          console.writeln(l.getLaunchConfiguration().getName());
          l.terminate();
          break; 
        }
      }

        org.eclipse.debug.core.ILaunchConfiguration[] allConfigurations=DebugPlugin.getDefault().getLaunchManager().getLaunchConfigurations();
        for (ILaunchConfiguration config : allConfigurations) {
            if (config.getName().equals("YOUR CONFIG NAME"))
            {
                DebugUITools.launch(config, "debug");
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (CoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{}
```

Notes:

1. Replace the YOUR CONFIG NAME with whatever you want
2. DebugUITools.launch can be changed to run or debug
3. Specify a macro name in the "Macro info" section
4. Assign an id started with 1.. If you want to be able to see this macro in the standard Eclipse key binding dialog

Now Click "ok"

Go to Windows-->Preferences-->General-->Keys

Select your macro's name and assign it to any key you want.

Finally dont forget to restart your eclipse again!

For more help:

http://sourceforge.net/p/practicalmacro/discussion/878739/thread/891ddd13

Comment: PracticallyMacro is great discovery for me.
And it was already on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437323/assigning-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-a-specific-eclipse-build-configuration

Comment: I have not not succeeded so far and need to switch to other tasks.

I used launchConfigurationType id https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/blob/master/org.nodeclipse.debug/plugin.xml#L21

As it is not only for me, I need changing plugin. Some launch related code here https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/tree/master/org.nodeclipse.debug/src/org/nodeclipse/debug/launch

Comment: Ultimate utility.. I am surprised why it is not a part of Eclipse.
Use Eclipse Market Place for easy installation.

Comment: I do not have "Editor Macro script (Beanshell)" why?